# Get value of seleceted child of ul - Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the value of the selected nav-stacked.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul class="nav  nav-stacked nav-pills" id="sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#events" data-toggle="tab">Events Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#count" data-toggle="tab">Count Report</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="registration">                    
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="count">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="events">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I get the value of the selected nav-stacked.??**

Also, by default `registration` is active, but its content is not shown. It only shows when I click on it,ie on-change event.

Comment: can you put your javascript code how you do it so we can check why it's not working? thanks

Comment: In the above, what would you want returned? "Registration Report"?

Comment: @DelightedD0D -  I would want the href value.

Comment: @Vainglory07- `sidebar = $("#sidebar li a").text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the href you're looking for like this:

```js
alert( $('#sidebar li.active a').attr('href') )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <ul class="nav  nav-stacked nav-pills" id="sidebar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#events" data-toggle="tab">Events Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#count" data-toggle="tab">Count Report</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="registration">                    
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="count">
        Some Content
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="events">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Also how do I show the content of `registration` tab upon reload. It gets viewed only after first clicking on others,ie either count or event, and then on registration. How do I view its content?

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure I understand what you mean